# EditText view encoding

Tags: android, character-encoding, http-post, android-edittext

In my application there are some kind of chat. When I receive message from server it displays well, but when I send message the text is all messed up. I suppose there are a problem with encoding, but how can I solve this? I already tried to setContentEncoding for postEntity, also I tried to encode string data with new String(old.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Nothink helped.

Comment: What does this have to do with EditText? Can you explain or change the the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're doing HTTP POST with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. Which library you use to generate the POST body data? If it's Apache httpmime, you'll need to pass an explicit `CharSet` parameter to your `StringBody` constructor, e.g.

```
CharSet cs = CharSet.defaultCharset();
MultipartEntity mp = new MultipartEntity();
mp.addPart("message", new StringBody("message to be encoded", cs));
```

If it's `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, have a look at `java.net.URLEncoder` class.